# No lock file found in /usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.lock

Tags: linux, system, administrator

I followed the instructions at this link which I found here on EE...http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/quickstart-fedora.html
Well after trying to stop nagios with command **service nagios stop** and after that to see its status with ***service nagios status*** the following message appears: "No lock file found in /usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.lock".  How do I resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the file exist? What's the output of ls /usr/local/nagios/var ?

Comment: In /usr/local/nagios/var                                                                              the file "nagios.lock" exists when nagios is started, but when I stop nagios the file "nagios.lock" disappeared. This file contains the PID nagios.

Comment: That's normal. The PID file would be removed on stopping Nagios.

Maybe it's a Nagios bug, but you could safely argue that the lack of nagios.lock means that Nagios isn't running.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. "No lock file found in /usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.lock" means that it isn't running.

If you run an `echo $?` directly after `service nagios status` while it isn't running, you'll notice that the exit code is 3.

3 is the correct value return code for that status as documented in the Linux Standard Base.

Some Sources:
https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/iniscrptact.html
http://ftp.novell.hu/pub/mirrors/ftp.novell.com/forge/library/SUSE%20Package%20Conventions/spc_init_scripts.html

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

UPDATE:

The error: "No lock file found in /usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.lock" simply means that nagios is not running.

Running the command above simply starts the nagios daemon and points it to a specific config file. The advantage to running this command manually over systemd is that when you run "service nagios start" this typically calls the /etc/rc.d/init.d/nagios script which contains a line with parametrized environment variables:

`$NagiosBin -d $NagiosCfgFile`

Because every system is different, not specifying either the bin nor config directories could lead to nagios breaking (stopping) when it tries to start using the default installation directory paths

Comment: Could you supply some explanation as to how this will solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.